# Что делает всё это - class, init, self. Python

Tags: python

```
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
```

Это только та часть кода, в которой я не понимаю и хочу разобраться. Сколько бы я не искал в инете и ютубе, всё как-то не так объясняют.

Comment: Прежде чем искать в интернете и особенно на ютубе, нужно знать хотя бы основы языка. Тогда хотя бы будешь знать, что искать, и сможешь понять объяснение.

Comment: Начинайте с азов. А то так Вам придется каждый час писать по вопросу.  И так все 2 семестра...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте по строкам

В первой строке мы создаём класс, который наследует класс `Frame` из модуля `TKinter`

```py
class Main(tk.Frame):
```

Дальше объявляется конструктор (действия, которые происходят при создании объекта этого класса). Параметр `self` является обязательным для всех методов объектов. В классах присутствует во всех функциях, кроме функций классов.

```py
    def __init__(self, root):
```

В конструкторе мы вызываем конструктор родительского класса (в нашем случае - `tk.Frame`), на что указывает конструкция `super().__init__(параметры)`

```py
        super().__init__(root)
```

После того, как был вызван конструктор родителя, вызывается функция `init_main()`. Слово `self` указывает на то, что функция взята именно из этого класса, а значит, вы приложили не весь код класса ;)

```py
        self.init_main()
```

Comment: Наверняка "как-то не так" объяснил! ;)

Comment: @Эникейщик ну разумеется ;)

Answer (score 1):

Класс `Main` наследуется от класса `tk.Frame` и в конструкторе сначала вызывает конструктор базового класса, а затем какой-то свой метод инициализации.

Comment: Хм.. Почему даже я это знаю?